# Update custom option value of item in cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, addtocart

I have custom option for one of my product.

I am able to save it's value in cart programatically using below code:

```
 $params = array(
         'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
         'product' => $product_id, 
         'qty'   =>1,
         'options'=>$options

 ); 
$this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$this->cart->save();
```

Where $options is array like below:

```
$options=array("option_id"=>"option_value");
```

Now i want to update this custom option value of cart item.

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you please tell us when or where do you want to update this option ?

Comment: Yes i have a custom field in minicart where on filling that field, i add specific product to cart (programatically) and on updating that field, i need to update that value in cart.

Comment: You have the solution of a plugin for the UpdateItemOptions action or UpdatePost action. If plugin is "too soft", you can override one of these actions situated in vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/, does that help or I did not understand ?

Comment: I can't get you. can you add any code example or reference link?

Comment: by the way, what i am doing right now is, when user updates that field, i remove product from cart and readd with updated value. but i understand that this is not the correct way. so i am looking for correct solution.